# How to ensure parent pipe is closed on parent crash in python multiprocessing?

Tags: python, pipe, multiprocessing

If I `close()` the parent end of a pipe, `poll()` will raise `IOError`/`EOFError`, which is the expected behaviour.

How to ensure the pipe gets closed when the parent terminates or, even worse, **crashes** so that the child can notice there is no one on the other end?

The following code will continue to print `Sleeping...` even though the parent has long since terminated:

```
import sys
import time

from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe

def f(parent_conn, conn):
    parent_conn.close()  # Close unused end

    for _ in range(10):
        if conn.poll():
            print 'Child:', conn.recv()

        print 'Sleeping...'
        time.sleep(0.3)

    conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
    p = Process(target=f, args=(parent_conn, child_conn))
    p.start()

    child_conn.close()  # Close unused end
    # parent_conn.close()  # If uncommented, the child notices the pipe is closed
    sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `multiprocessing.Pipe` object is a message oriented interface over a simple `os.pipe`.

The `multiprocessing.Connection.poll` method has several limitations. Not only it cannot detect closed pipes but it can also lead to deadlocks if the message sent from the other side of the pipe is too big to be read at once.

A workaround I usally employ which works only on Unix is using the `select` function.

```
from select import select
from multiprocessing import Pipe

reader, writer = Pipe()

print('Waiting for data coming to the Pipe.')
if select([reader], [], [], None)[0]:
    print('Data available on the Pipe.')
    print(reader.recv())
```

Comment: So I guess a cross-platform workaround would be to pass a _ping_-like message from the child to the parent and if no _pong_ is received within a reasonable time frame, assume the pipe is closed and no longer valid.

Maybe also send another _goodbye_ message to the parent so if it turns out the parent was busy doing other things and could not respond to the _ping_ in time, it knows the child closed the pipe on purpose.

Comment: Rather than complicating the logic so much, I would replace the pipe with a TCP socket. The underlying implementation already takes care of disconnections and you get the benefit of a solution which works locally and remotely.